# Route all trafic for specific ip over specific network interface

Tags: linux, networking, routing

I have a linux server that needs to get some routing. I'm fairly new at this and i don't find any clear source on google.

The setup should be simple:
All traffic to a server on ip 192.168.72.20 should be sent over interface 3.
All other interfaces don't matter at the moment.

Here you have the output for `route -n`

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
192.168.72.0    0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth0
192.168.72.0    0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth1
192.168.72.0    0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth2
192.168.72.0    0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth3
192.168.72.0    0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth4
169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     1002   0        0 eth0
0.0.0.0         192.168.72.12   0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0
```

Comment: Are you using the old fashioned ifconfig and route command or the modern ip commands? (old ones would be something like `route add -host 192.168.72.20 GW eth3_ip`)

Comment: i don't know, i guess the old ones, how can i check that?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Try:

`ip route add 192.168.72.20/32 dev eth3`

Comment: Just a note: to permanently keep this configuration make sure you add it to `/etc/rc.local` or your distro's equivalent.  It won't persist between reboots.

Comment: I tried this same format for mapping an IP to the wlan0 on Ubuntu 14.04 and got `RTNETLINK answers: Invalid argument` I had to remove the /** from the IP so I ended up with: `sudo ip route add 192.168.50.15 dev wlan0` -- thought I'd mention that in case anyone else ran into this issue. Thank you for your answer ultrasawblade, it was helpful.

Comment: Do not forget `via <gateway_ip>` if the target IP is not directly reachable!

Comment: How would I add another entry saying "use this interface for all other destination IPs"?

Comment: That's called setting a default gateway and is done with `ip route add default via $ROUTER_IP dev $INTERFACE`.

Comment: Thanks! What would be the `$ROUTER_IP`?

Comment: @LawrenceC, that is not a default gateway. OP stated "All traffic to a server on ip 192.168.72.20 should be sent over interface 3", which is a single IP he wants to route. A default gateway (or gateway of last resort) is a route that sends all traffic that does not have a specific route in a specific table to be sent to an interface or far end ip. They already have a default gateway defined as `0.0.0.0         192.168.72.12   0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0`

Comment: @Dave well, you could set eth3 as the default gateway, but your "automatic" routes you get from eth0, eth1, and eth2 (by virtue of being directly connected) would still catch traffic unless you removed the IP address and subnet configuration from them.  It sounded like OP wanted all traffic to go out of eth3 regardless of what eth0, eth1, and eth2 were doing.

Answer (score 0):

you might need "via" in the command:

```
ip route add 192.168.72.20/32 via dev eth3
```

See this similar issue [CentOS 7 custom routes with 2 NIC's](https://superuser.com/questions/1668445/centos-7-custom-routes-with-2-nics)

Comment: No, `via` specifically indicates that a gateway address follows. The output interface is a separate parameter from a gateway.