# Undo routing table addition

Tags: networking, ip, routing, ip-address, routing-table

I followed the instructions in [this question](https://superuser.com/q/575249/137014) to add an entry to my routing table to [solve my collision problem](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/195274/ssh-over-vpn-blocked-on-certain-networks) while on a public Wi-Fi network. This is what I ran:

```
ip route add 10.52.0.14/32 dev tun0
```

The problem is now I always have to connect to VPN (`tun0`) to access that IP, even when I am on the university network.

1. How do I remove this entry? I can't seem to get the syntax of `ip route del` correct.
2. Is there a way to persist this and not have to add/remove the entry every time I am on a public Wi-Fi network?
3. In the add command, what does `dev` mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. To remove the route execute `ip route del 10.52.0.14`

   For Debian-based distros, you could add an entry to /etc/network/interfaces (see [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/84552/set-persistent-routing-table-on-debian) for details)

   `dev` indicates that the parameter that follows (in your case `tun0`) is the network device to operate on

Comment: Thanks. I'm using Linux Mint (Ubuntu/Debian-based) and I have both the `ip` and `route` commands available

Comment: @rink.attendant.6 I've updated item 2 for Debian