# CentOS 7 custom routes with 2 NIC's

Tags: linux, networking, centos, routing, iptables

I have two interfaces o my CentOS 7:

- ens192 - 10.70.87.200/24
- ens224 - 192.168.11.200/24

tcp/22 has to be listening only on ens192

- I want all internet traffic but a few networks do be going out via ens224
- Traffic for 10.70.87.0/16 and 10.80.0.0/16 should go through ens192

```
iptables -L -n
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
```

I tried adding a custom route like this: `ip route add 10.7.80.80/32 dev ens192` but doesn't work. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to add the route like this:

`ip route add 10.70.0.0/16 via 10.70.87.254` where 10.70.87.254 is the gateway on the ens192 - 10.70.87.200/24 network